# Direct copy of mongodb Document object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, document

Long story short, I am working inside of a giant nasty recursive function that is building out a mongo Document object. I have to extend the functionality of this function to support complex queries and need to know how to create a direct copy (not object reference) of a mongo Document object. Is there any way of doing this? The current implementation does the following:

```
private Document generateArrayAddsDoc(DataChanges dataChanges, Document filter)
    {
        Document arrayUpdatesDoc = new Document();
        generateArrayDocImpl(arrayUpdatesDoc, null, dataChanges, DataChanges.Type.MODEL_ADD, filter, 0);
        return arrayUpdatesDoc;
    }
```

Here is the nasty recursive function just for context:

```
private void generateArrayDocImpl(Document arrayUpdateDoc, String parentFieldName, DataChanges dataChanges, DataChanges.Type type, Document filter, int currentLevel)
    {
        switch (dataChanges.getType())
        {
            case MODEL_UPDATE:
            {
                for (DataChange dataChange : dataChanges.getDataChanges())
                {
                    if (dataChange.getNewValue() instanceof DataChanges)
                    {
                        DataChanges arrayChanges = (DataChanges) dataChange.getNewValue();

                        Document arrayDoc = new Document();
                        String dotFieldName = generateDotFieldName(parentFieldName, dataChange.getFieldName());

                        if (type == DataChanges.Type.MODEL_ADD || type == DataChanges.Type.MODEL_DELETE)
                        {
                            generateArrayDocImpl(arrayDoc, dotFieldName, arrayChanges, type, filter, currentLevel+1);
                        }

                        if (!arrayDoc.isEmpty())
                        {
                            if (currentLevel > 0)
                            {
                                arrayUpdateDoc.append(dotFieldName, arrayDoc);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                arrayUpdateDoc = arrayDoc; // need to direct copy instead of referencing here
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                break;
            }
            case ARRAY_UPDATE:
            {
                List<Document> updateDocsList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataChange dataChange : dataChanges.getDataChanges())
                {
                    Document arrayElementDoc = null;
                    DataChanges arrayElementChanges = (DataChanges) dataChange.getNewValue();

                    if (arrayElementChanges.getType() == type)
                    {
                        arrayElementDoc = generateFieldUpdatesDoc(arrayElementChanges, filter);
                    }
                    else if (arrayElementChanges.getType() == DataChanges.Type.MODEL_UPDATE)
                    {
                        String dotFieldName = generateDollarSignIndexedFieldName(parentFieldName, dataChange.getFieldName());
                        generateArrayDocImpl(arrayUpdateDoc, dotFieldName, arrayElementChanges, type, filter, currentLevel+1);
                    }

                    if (null != arrayElementDoc && !arrayElementDoc.isEmpty())
                    {
                        updateDocsList.add(arrayElementDoc);
                    }
                }

                if (!updateDocsList.isEmpty() && type == DataChanges.Type.MODEL_ADD)
                {
                    arrayUpdateDoc.append("$each", updateDocsList);
                }

                if (!updateDocsList.isEmpty() && type == DataChanges.Type.MODEL_DELETE)
                {
                    String fieldName = pullFieldNameFromList(updateDocsList);
                    List<String> valuesToDelete = getValuesToDelete(updateDocsList);

                    Document doc = new Document();
                    doc.append("$in", valuesToDelete);

                    arrayUpdateDoc.append(fieldName, doc);
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Where this function is doing "arrayUpdateDoc = arrayDoc;", I need to copy document into a new object because arrayDoc is being destroyed after this function call is finished resulting in a bug. Any recommendations on doing a direct object copy (not by reference) of a mongo Document object would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the documents entry map and pass it to the constructor when creating a new document:

```
Document original = someDocument;
Document clone = new Document(original.entrySet());
```

In your case:

```
arrayUpdateDoc = new Document(arrayDoc.entrySet());
```

//Edit:

I got that wrong.
However, Document implements `Map<String, Object>`.
That means that the following should work:

```
arrayUpdateDoc = new Document(arrayDoc);
```

//Another edit:

What you are trying to do will not work in Java. e.g:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String test = "test";
    System.out.println(test);
    someMethod(test);
    System.out.println(test);
}

public static void someMethod(String test)
{
    test = "changed";
}
```

the output is:

```
test
test
```

The callers reference will not be updated to the new object. The reference is copied when you call the method.
So, as far as I know, you will need a return type for your method.

Comment: this does not work as the constructor Document(Set<String>, Set<Map.Entry<String,Object>>) is undefined

Comment: This still does not seem to work. I can get this function to work properly by making it return the new object per your suggestion but it still seems to be using the reference of the old object when I replace the Document being passed as an argument with the newly created one

Comment: I would like to keep the implementation consistent with what is already in place by keeping it a void function and just updating the Document object that is being passed in